# Properly calling an authorization Karate feature with arguments

Tags: karate

I have an authentication feature working, but would like to make it reusable. I'm not able to get working through the methods I've tried so far.

The standalone method that works is:

```
# Created at 10/4/18
Feature: #Authentication Management
Background:
  * url gatewayUrl
  * def myid = 'myid'
  * def mysecret = 'mysecret'
  Scenario: # Generate authentication token for x user
    Given path 'mypath'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    And request 'grant_type=api_key&myid=' + myid + '&mysecret=' + mysecret
    When method post
    Then status 200
    * print response.Token
```

Here is the working POST request for this one:

```
1 > POST <authURL>
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 108
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: <authURL>
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/10.0.2)
grant_type=api_key&myid=myId&mysecret=mySecret
```

I'd like to replace **myid** and **mysecret** with the args from the feature that performs the call. Using '#(myid)' and '(#mysecret)' doesn't seem to work anywhere but when defining param(s). Is there a way to do this replacement, or another equivalent way of building up the request data to send?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is worth reading through the docs carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

Try this:

```
Feature: #Authentication Management
Scenario: # Generate authentication token for x user
  Given url gatewayUrl      
  And path 'mypath'
  And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  And request 'grant_type=api_key&myid=' + myid + '&mysecret=' + mysecret
  When method post
  Then status 200
```

And then call as follows:

```
Feature: main
Background:
  * def result = call read('auth.feature') { myid: 'actualid', mysecret: 'actualsecret' }
  * def token = result.response.Token
  # remaining test uses token
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.